# Using XMLHttpRequest in react is refreshing my page and resetting my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a rudimentary application to learn React. I have some data stored in a JSON file that I'm reading from using `json-loader`. However I'd also like to write to this file. I have a python script on my backend which writes to a file (I don't believe this script is the issue but I can include it if needed).

When a user clicks the "next" button, I'm trying to send a request to the backend to update the json file. The issue is that whenever the button is clicked, the page refreshes and the state resets meaning the user cannot progress through the site.

Here is the button in question:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-info" id="continue_btn" onClick={() => nextStep()}>
     Continue
</button>
```

And nextStep():

```
  const nextStep = () => {
    if (step + 1 > progress[props.tutorial]["total-steps"])
      return;
    else {
      updateStep();
      setStep(step + 1);
    }
  };
```

and updateStep():

```
  const updateStep = () => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", `http://localhost:8000/store_progress/${props.page}/`, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.send(JSON.stringify({
      "progress": step + 1
    }));
  }
```

The JSON file does get written to with the correct information, I just need to cancel the page reload so that the state can be appropriately updated and the user can progress through the page.

I'll be happy to provide any additional information if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: is your button inside a `form` element? why you dont use `fetch`?

Comment: @Nico it is not inside a form element. I tried to use fetch and got the exact same result.

Comment: try `onClick={(e) => nextStep(e)}>` and then `e.preventDefault()` inside `nextStep() `

Comment: @Nico Just tried, same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update your json file you trigger HMR because you are importing the file in your code and not getting it from the server

Comment: How do I get around this problem?
I tried making a get request using useEffect() setting the json file to the json file returned from the server but the page still refreshes.

Comment: @JohnnyLeek are you still importing the JSON file in the code? like this `import data from 'file.json'`

Comment: I just uninstalled json-loader and removed all instances of import JSON and it's still refreshing. I believe your answer to be correct because it doesn't appear to be refreshing the page when I build the app and push it to the server, but I would still like to figure out what's causing the hot-loader to refresh here as well.

Comment: Update, for whatever reason for the past 5 minutes the hot loader hasn't actually been refreshing my app? Stopping and running npm run start appears to have fixed the problem. Thank you!